# Setting custom cursor using jquery input variable?

Tags: jquery, css, cursor

I am trying to set a custom cursor via a simple form. The form has an input box in which the user would type a direct URL to a cursor/image and when the button is clicked that URL is set to a variable.

The variable is being set but I can't pass it to the jquery cursor url eg:

```
$('.customCur').css( 'cursor', 'url(str), auto' );
```

This is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="customCur">
 <head>
<title>Cursor Demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Set Cursor Demo</h1>

<form action="">
Cursor URL: <input type="text" name="cursorURL"><br />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Set Cursor">
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( '#btn' ).click(function() {
        var str = $( 'input' ).val();
        $('.customCur').css( 'cursor', 'url(str), auto' );
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate your string variable like so:

```
 $('.customCur').css( 'cursor', 'url(' + str + '), auto' );
```

As you had it, `str` was simply being treated as a string and you want the value of the variable instead.